# Webpack postcss prefixer in vue-cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3, postcss-loader

I need to prefix the Bulma css classes by using webpack. I found an example but my app uses Vue CLI 3 and I'm not sure how to translate the webpack config to a vue.config.js.

[This is the webpack config](https://github.com/uu1t-sandbox/example--webpack-config-prefixed-bulma/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

In my `vue.config.js` I have the following:

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('css-prefixer')
      .use(['style-loader', 'css-loader'])
      .loader('postcss-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        // Prefixer goes here
        return options
      })
  }
```

Which gives some internal webpack errors.

Comment: bulma doesn't need any special configuration in `vue-cli` to work correctly. npm install the module, import it in your own `.scss` file, import that `.scss` file in your `main.js` and you're done

Comment: Yes I know but I want to prefix all CSS classes that bulma has. Because it uses very generic names such as `.label` which causes problems when I dynamically load my app into an existing website.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? Having the same issue as my client's site is using Bootstrap 3.4 and we need to integrate bulma in newer sections.

Comment: I ended up taking the code in the link and generating the prefixed Bulma css with that. Then I just added those to my assets in my Vue project. So Bulma doesn't come from node_modules as I would like but it's good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Just manage to do it in my vue.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const prefixer = require('postcss-prefixer')

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          prefixer({
            prefix: 'b-'
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work well. It prefixes all the css classes with `b-` :<

Comment: Very nice, I have tried this example with "const prefixer = require('postcss-prefix-selector');" and works well. It adds the prefix before all css selectors.

Comment: Nice. I just used the technique suggested by @darpet using `postcss-prefix-selector` to scope an entire CSS library to one `<div/>` on the page

Comment: It prefixes everything everything in css file, <style> tags but not in HTML with .vue files. How to go about it?